# Unity-Error within Tree Editor

Tags: unity, unityscript, tree

I've been making a tree in with the Tree Editor in Unity, and for a realistic effect, I need to make **all** the leaves face a general direction, the problem is that most of them don't face that direction and are upside down or sideways.

So you further understand, i'll add some images.

I'd like all the leaves to face in this direction.

(Image 1) In here you can see that some leaves are upside down or sideways and i'd like to make all the leaves face the same way.
[image: Image 1.]

[image]

(Image 2) In here you can see the leaf is facing up and this is the way I would like all the leafs to face.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.